# Strange page numbering with onesided book and hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, books

The following code produces page numbers which show in SumatraPDF as 1, 1.1, 2. I expect the pages to be numbered 1, 2, 3. This numbering is caused by the combination of `oneside` option for the book document class, and the `hyperref` package. What is the reason for this numbering, and how can it be fixed?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Page 1}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Page 2}
Text
\chapter{Page 3}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem here on TeXlive 2015.

Comment: I have MikTex 2.9. Perhaps it's a bug which has been corrected.

Comment: BTW, I also don't have pages 1,2,3, but rather *empty*,1,2.  This is due to the fact that in general the title page shouldn't have a number.

Comment: The printed page numbers in the bottom/top of the page are correct. I mean the current page number that the PDF-viewer reports. Do you also mean these?

Comment: `hyperref` defaults to passing the *logical* page number to the viewer.  This is really helpful if you have a preface which is numbered in roman and the main part in arabic, because then you can enter pages like “iv” into the viewer and jump to the correct *physical* page.  You can suppress this by passing `pdfpagelabels=false` to `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks for the option-flag! What is still open though, is why the logical page number of the first chapter is 1.1? If oneside is replaced with twoside, then the 1.1 disappears.

Comment: I’m equally perplexed.  I would argue this is a bug with `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`.  The page number of the title page and the following page should not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document from the question has the following page numbers:

**Physical/absolute page vs. \thepage**
1 vs. 1
2 vs. 1
3 vs. 2

Class `book` uses environment `titlepage` for `\maketitle`, which resets the page number to one in the end of the environment.

Package `hyperref` enables option `pdfpagelabels` by default (not in too old versions). It uses `\thepage` for the logical page number, that means, the pages are numbered as `1`, `1`, and `2`:

Tested viewers with support for logical page numbers:
* Evince 2.32
* AR DC 2015
* SumatraPDF 3.0

The first two show: 1 (1 of 3), 1 (2 of 3), 2 (3 of 3)

SumatraPDF shows: 1 (1/3), 1 (2/3), 2 (3/3)

Maybe, the version of SumatraPDF, you are using, is different and contains a bug.

A better page label for the title page can be set by `\thispdfpagelabel{Title}`.
And the duplicate destination warning can be removed by locally setting `pageanchor=false`, because a page anchor is probably not needed for the title page (presumably no index entries to the title page, ...).

Example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Page 1}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \thispdfpagelabel{Title}
  \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
  \maketitle
\endgroup
\chapter{Page 2}
Text
\chapter{Page 3}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: SumatraPDF indeed seems to have some bug; Acrobat Reader and Foxit Reader work fine. I updated SumatraPDF from 3.0 to 3.1.1, but the 1.1 page number persists. I'll report this bug to the creators of SumatraPDF.