# Two pages "1" with package hyperref

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, counters

When compiling a LaTeX document, I get two pages numbered at "1": the front page and the first of the table of contents. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\end{document}
```

When compiling this (using simply `pdflatex file.tex`), I get this:

[image]

But when I remove the line `\usepackage{hyperref}`, page numbers are fine. Note that I need this package to have links to pages in my table of contents, but maybe there's a better way to do so. What is happening here ? How do I get normal page numbers ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you try to compile the file multiple times (i.e., 2 or 3 times)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did and the result doesn't change

Comment: Near duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276925/strange-page-numbering-with-onesided-book-and-hyperref-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by the report documentclass trying to help you out by not numbering the first page, which is desired in many cases.

To get the normal page number as you want you can simply set the page counter to 2 right after the title page was made. You can do this with the command `\setcounter{page}{2}`.

Here is the edited MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{2}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It did the job, thanks. Although I'm not sure that it is caused by the report documentclass, as the same report works fine when I remove hyperref.